# Substitute column value in each row of a 2d array based on other rows in the same array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, mapping

I have an array like so:

```
$array = [
    ['record' => 1, 'sponsor' => 2, 'email' => 'some@email.com'],
    ['record' => 2, 'sponsor' => 2, 'email' => 'some1@email.com'],
    ['record' => 3, 'sponsor' => 2, 'email' => 'some2@email.com'],
    ['record' => 4, 'sponsor' => 2, 'email' => 'some3@email.com'],
];
```

Each row has a unique `record` and `email` and the `sponsor` key is related to the `record`. So, instead of an integer, I am trying to replace the value of the `sponsor` key with the corresponding `email` based on the `record`, something like this:

```
$array = [
    ['record' => 1, 'sponsor' => 'some1@email.com', 'email' => 'some@email.com'],
    ['record' => 2, 'sponsor' => 'some1@email.com', 'email' => 'some1@email.com'],
    ['record' => 3, 'sponsor' => 'some1@email.com', 'email' => 'some2@email.com'],
    ['record' => 4, 'sponsor' => 'some1@email.com', 'email' => 'some3@email.com'],
];
```

I have tried using a `foreach` loop but it doesn't give me the expected result:

```
$yes = [];
foreach ($array as $key => $arr) {
    if ( ! empty($arr['sponsor']) ) {
        if ( $arr['sponsor'] == $array[$key]['record'] ) {
            $yes[] = ['sponsor' => $array[$key]['email']];
        }
    }
    $yes[] = [
        'record' => $array[$key]['record'], 
        'email' => $array[$key]['email'],
        'sponsor' => $array[$key]['sponsor'],
    ];
}
print_r($yes);
```

Comment: The way your array is displayed. Their is no key on the "record". So the $key=>$arr will not give you what you want. Just loop through the array and build a new array with the changes you want to make.

Comment: Of course, building a new array is the goal. I'm just having a challenge on how to check for the relationship between the value of the `sponsor` and `record`, and then replace with the corresponding `email`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `record` is unique, I recommend rebuilding `$arr` using this value as the key. Then you loop again to replace your value for `$sponsor` –

```
$indexedArray = [];
foreach ($array as $v) {
  $indexedArray[$v['record']] = $v;
}   
foreach ($indexedArray as $record => $v) {
  if (isset($indexedArray[$v['sponsor']]) && isset($indexedArray[$v['sponsor']]['email'])) {
    $indexedArray[$record]['sponsor'] = $indexedArray[$v['sponsor']]['email'];
  }
}
$yes = array_values($indexedArray);
```

Comment: It is misleading to call your mapping/lookup array `$indexedArray` because it is NOT an "indexed array" until `array_values()` is called.  Your mapping array is unnecessarily complex/deep for this task.  A flat array will consume less memory and be simpler to access.  In the `foreach()` modifying by reference will make your code more concise by avoid the use of first level keys.  When logically requiring two `isset()` calls, you can call `isset()` once and pass in both elements as its parameters.  Consider the approaches in my answer as simpler techniques.

Answer (score 1):

Create a lookup array with `record` values as keys and `email` values as values, then overwrite the sponsor value in each row based on the corresponding lookup value.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/CcIZa))

```
$lookup = array_column($array, 'email', 'record');
var_export(
    array_map(fn($row) => array_replace($row, ['sponsor' => $lookup[$row['sponsor']]]), $array)
);
```

Or with a classic loop: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/tqp3b))

```
$lookup = array_column($array, 'email', 'record');
foreach ($array as &$row) {
    $row['sponsor'] = $lookup[$row['sponsor']];
}
var_export($array);
```

If there is a chance that a given `sponsor` value might not be found in the lookup, then use `$lookup[$row['sponsor']] ?? 'some fallback'` when you try to access the lookup array.  This way you will not generate warnings/errors.  This is a more concise way of checking `isset()`.

---

p.s. Bear in mind that using [the array union operator won't work properly](https://3v4l.org/C7Smm) in this case.